# Edit image alignment in Wordpress twentysixteen child theme on attachment page

Tags: customization, images, css

I'm quite new at wordpress. I want to align the image on this page further over to the right so there is more space for the text (which is now a narrow column). I think I need to add something in the twentysixteen child theme css file, but cannot work out what....something about the .entry-attachment?? I've tried various things to no avail.....

this is the page: http://www.heathergaeblersavoie.com/gallery/attachment/asymetric-pear-drops/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines to your css file in your child theme.  You can change the percentages to suit your needs.  (I've provided a starting point of what I think looks pretty good)

```
//text size
.entry-footer {
    width: 30% !important;
}
//picture size
.entry-content {
    margin-left: 55% !important;
    width: 30%!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did that, but it didn't work until I enclosed them in this line: @media screen and (min-width: 61.5625em) { } and now it works!!

Comment: no problem.  can you mark as answered please? (check mark to the left of my answer)